# How to set unique constraint in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, constraints, unique-constraint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server 2005 How Create a Unique Constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64981/sql-server-2005-how-create-a-unique-constraint)
>   [Add unique constraint in SQL Server 2008 GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643023/add-unique-constraint-in-sql-server-2008-gui)

I have a table in Sql Server 2008 named customer.To the email field I want to add a unique constraint-so that email should not be repeated (not using query). I tried in the way as shown in the image and is not able to set the constraint. Please help.
[image]

Comment: @JonH I can. Try refreshing.

Comment: @ean5533 - I meant its so small, thats okay I went and snatched the imgurl from the post.

Comment: Do it through the indexes and keys dialogue not the check constraints one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64981/sql-server-2005-how-create-a-unique-constraint

Comment: @ean5533 When I try as  [stackoverflow.com/questions/64981/…](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64981/sql-server-2005-how-create-a-unique-constraint) a unique+primary key is set on email column.I have a primary key custid .email field just need to be unique

Answer (score 2):

Check constraints are for checking to see if data in a row matches a formula - SSMS is correct that you can't have a blank forumla there.

What you want to do is go to Indexes/Keys and add a new index on the email field and set it to Is Unique=Yes and type Unique Key (as suggested by hvd, you can also create a unique Index from here by selecting Type=Index).

Comment: I *think* merely setting "Is Unique" will create a unique index, not a unique constraint. But unique constraints can be added from the same window.

Answer (score 1):

the email **shouldn't be TEXT** type

[image]

Comment: Not sure why you make the point about `text`? In the screenshot in the OP you can see `va` after email indicating it is `varchar`

Comment: *Just in case* if its a TEXT type it won't appear on the columns list when you're choosing

Comment: Ah right see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like:

```
ALTER TABLE Comment ADD CONSTRAINT uc_Comment UNIQUE (CommentId, Comment)
```

CommentId is PK.

I believe it actually creates an index for this.