# SQL Query to update department

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a special scenario to update my department without having any conflicts with the existing records.

Can someone tell me how to write a query for it?

Here is my need.

Table `Dept`:

```
DeptID             DeptName
-----------------------------    
D001               Accounts
D002               HR
D003               Dev
D004               Support
```

Now, I want to update one of the existing records and make sure that it should not allow duplicates (Either `deptid` or `deptname` and both).

Ex:

- Case 1: When I try to update `D001`, I should not give `DeptID` like D002, D003 or D004 as they are already existing.
- Case 2: When I try to edit `DeptName`, it should not accept any of the existing DeptNames

Comment: You should create a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT on each column

Comment: Already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64981/sql-server-2005-how-create-a-unique-constraint

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off storing your department identifier as a `INT` / primary key that auto increments. That would take care of the ID's being unique.

```
ALTER TABLE Dept 
ADD DeptID int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY
```

If you really want the format `D001`, on your values, you can add this when you retrieve data:

```
SELECT  DeptID,
        'D' + RIGHT('000' + CAST(DeptID AS VARCHAR(3)), 3)
FROM    Dept
```

Then you only need to worry about department names being unique.

With the department names, firstly you should have application logic that prevents duplicate values being added and secondly, you can perform a check when you attempt to add a new value:

```
DECLARE @DeptToAdd VARCHAR(20) = 'Cleaning'

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Dept WHERE DeptName = @DeptToAdd)
BEGIN
-- INSERT CODE IF IT DOES NOT EXIST
  INSERT INTO Dept (DeptName)
  VALUES (@DeptToAdd)
-- or UPDATE
  UPDATE Dept
  SET DeptName = @DeptToAdd
  WHERE DeptId = 123
END
```

This will only insert or update the value if it doesn't already exist.

On top of this you can enforce this with a [**unique constraint**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643023/add-unique-constraint-in-sql-server-2008-gui).

Answer (score 0):

AS @mxix points out, a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT will prevent you adding duplicates (and you should add them), but it will give you an error message if you try. Here's a query that does nothing if you try to add an existing value

```
INSERT INTO Dept(DeptID)
SELECT 'ANewValue' 
WHERE 'ANewValue' NOT IN (SELECT DeptId FROM Dept)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the existance of `deptid` or `deptname` and then insert the values to the `dept` table,

For `INSERT`:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT DeptID 
              FROM Dept 
              WHERE DeptID = 'D005' OR DeptName = 'maintanance')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Dept (DeptID, DeptName) VALUES ('D005', 'maintanance')
END
```

For `UPDATE`:

Case1:

```
UPDATE Dept 
SET DeptID = 'D005' 
WHERE DeptName = 'some name'  AND DeptID NOT IN (SELECT DeptID FROM Dept)
```

Case 2:

```
UPDATE Dept 
SET DeptName = 'Some name'
WHERE DeptID = 'some id'  AND DeptName NOT IN (SELECT DeptName FROM Dept)
```

Comment: For insert, this will work. But I'm looking for update

Comment: @jestges: Check the updated result and reply the status.